# .htaccess RewriteEngine not working

Tags: .htaccess

I have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/test$ /home.php
```

So `mysite.com/home.php` and `mysite.com/test` are supposed to be the same now?
But when I go to `mysite.com/test` I get a 404 error.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of leading slash in your rule.

Change that to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/?$ /home.php [L,NC]
```

`.htaccess` is per directory config hence Apache doesn't match leading `/` while matching a URI `/test1

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)